# Force user to test dependencies by not counting coverage for indirect tests

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript, unit-testing

Question is to verify if such concept/functionality exists in any testing framework in any language

**Case**

I have class A which contains class B.

In tests for class A i'm triggering methods A and due to that also of class B -> Coverage here is counted for A and B

**2 Questions**

- A) How do I need to make that my CC tool to not count CC if I'm not
  directly testing class B
- B) Is there a way to achieve it without
  mocking and then setting the behavior of mocks?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by using dependency injection of class B into class A, such that you are able to provide a mock of class B instead of the real thing. For instance:

```
class A {
    function constructor (B classB) {
        this.B = B; // now do stuff with it
    }
}
```

this is opposed to something like:

```
class A {
    function constructor () {
        this.B = new B(); // now do stuff with it
    }
}
```

So when you test, you provide a mock of Class B to Class A under test, and then you wont be covering Class B in your code coverage report.

That being said, code coverage is not the best metric. Its a cool tool to know if you missed areas of the code to test, but it's an easily gamed metric, and it can't replace well thought out tests that might cover the same area f code multiple times.

Also, it's important to consider if you are writing unit tests, or implementation tests. There is a difference. In my experience, it only makes sense to mock out code if you need to to exclude integrations in your test. Otherwise, test through the public entrypoint of your code to get a more wholistic, and easier to maintain unit test.